# Use of Maps for record inserts

Tags: map, collection, insert

I totally get and use Maps for updating records. No question.

If I am getting duplicate entries in my List for inserts (obviously this is poor coding which can be avoided). Know that.

Let's say I want to insert records using Map mapOfNewRecords - this will no work as I don't yet know the record Id to be inserted.

Is there a proven pattern for using maps on insert?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question. You never have the Ids of the records on insert... because they don't exist and therefore don't have an id. What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: What does "duplicate" mean in this context? All you need is a unique value to map by, but you have not specified any unique fields for your use case.

Comment: Are you suggesting that you are inserting a map of records that have duplicate records and don't know how to generate the Key?  If so, a simple incremental loop while building the map will generate a unique keyID for each record and allow the insert.

Comment: Thanks guys, sounds like it was a stupid question anyway.  When I'm updating records I'm always using a Map of the objects. So I do something like: update mapOfRecords.value();  If I'm inserting or upsetting records I cannot use as map. Like this as an example Map<Id, Account> because I don't know all my Ids.  I wonder if this would work Map<Account,Account>  Maybe that's not good practice or perhaps not even possible.  I'll stick with using list collection.  Just curious.